# SQL query - filter primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I am using microsoft sql server and my query is of the following format (table1 primary key is (A,B)):

```
Select table1.A, table1.B, table2.C, Table3.D
from table1
left outer join table2 on table1.A = table2.A
left outer join tabl3 on table1.B = table3.B

//Here comes the question
//Except (A,B) in ( select A,B from BadTable)
```

How could I do it nicely? I was thinking about finding the set of CORRECT keys using sth like (cannot use except - running sql server 2000)

```
Select A,B
from table1
not exists ( select A,B from bad table)
```

and then inner join that with the main query. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select table1.A, table1.B, table2.C, Table3.D
from table1 T1
left outer join table2 on table1.A = table2.A
left outer join tabl3 on table1.B = table3.B
where not exists (select 1 from badTable where A = T1.A and B = T1.B)
```

would be a good way

Answer (score 0):

```
Select table1.A, table1.B, table2.C, Table3.D ,badtable.*
from table1 
left join table2 on table1.A = table2.A 
left join table3 on table1.B = table3.B 
left join badtable on table1.a = badtable.a
    and table1.b = badtable.b
where badtable.a is null
```